# Not getting a smooth curve using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4

I am trying to fitting a mixed effects models using `lme4` package. Unfortunately I cannot share the data that i am working with. Also i couldn't find a toy data set is relevant to my problem  . So here i have showed the steps that i followed so far :

First i plotted the overall trend of the data as follows :

```
p21 <- ggplot(data = sub_data, aes(x = age_cent, y = y))
p21+ geom_point() + geom_smooth()
```

[image]

Based on this , there seems to be a some nonlinear trend in the data. Hence I tried to fit the quadratic model as follows :

```
sub_data$age_cent=sub_data$age-mean((sub_data)$age)
sub_data$age_centsqr=(sub_data$age-mean((sub_data)$age))^2

m1= lmer(y ~ 1 + age_cent +  age_centsqr +(1 | id) , sub_data, REML = TRUE)
```

In the above model i only included a random intercept because i don't have enough data to include both random slope and intercept.Then i extracted the predictions of these model at population level as follows :

```
pred1=predict(m1,re.form=NA)
```

Next I plotted these predictions along with a smooth quadratic function like this

```
    p21+ geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ I(x) + I(x^2)
 ,col="red")+geom_line(aes(y=pred1,group = id) ,col="blue", lwd = 0.5)
```

[image]

In the above plot , the curve corresponds to predictions are not smooth. Can any one helps me to figure out the reason for that ?
I am doing anything wrong here ?

**Update :** 
As  eipi10 pointed out , this may due to fitting different curves for different people.

But when i tried the same thing using a toy data set which is in the lme4 package , i got the same curve for each person as follows :

```
m1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1+I(Days) + (1+ Days| Subject) , data = sleepstudy)



pred1new1=predict(m1,re.form=NA)

p21 <- ggplot(data = sleepstudy, aes(x = Days, y = Reaction))
p21+ geom_point() + geom_smooth()
p21+ geom_point() + geom_smooth()+ geom_line(aes(y=pred1new1,group = Subject) ,col="red", lwd = 0.5)
```

[image]

What may be the reason the for different results ? Is this due to unbalance of the data ? 
The data i used collected in 3 time steps and some people didn't have it for all 3 time steps. But the toy data set is a balanced data set.

Thank you

Comment: The `predict` function is returning predictions for every data row. It looks like you have predictions for each level of `id`, and you added `group=id` as an aesthetic in `geom_line`, so you'll get a separate line for each `id`.

Comment: Also, it looks like `pred1` is a vector of predictions. I don't know if it's causing any issues here, but in general it's safer to include the predictions in the data frame passed to `ggplot` (`sub_data` in this case) so that you can be sure the relationship between the values in `pred` and the rows of `sub_data` remain consistent.

Comment: @eipi10 Thank you for the suggestions. does this can be due to unbalanced   of data ?  Please refer the updated question , where i include a plot using a toy data set.

Comment: You need both an unbalanced data set and a non-linear (e.g. polynomial) model for the fixed effects to see this effect.  I'll put together an example when I get a chance.  You should be able to get prettier graphs by using `newdata=expand.grid(levels(group),unique(x_values)))` to fill in missing values in your prediction frame.

Comment: @BenBolker It is great if you can put some example. Thanks . Also can you explain which variable you treated as x_values ? Is it the time related  variable ?

Comment: @BenBolker  Also in the toy example , the the X variables which Days had same set of values (0-9 Days) for each Subject. But in my example, I used the age  of each person at each wave (time step)  as the X variable. So the age values are not same for each person at each time step. I think that may be another reason for this different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** use `expand.grid()` or something like it to generate a balanced/evenly spaced sample for every group (if you have a strongly nonlinear curve you may want to generate a larger/more finely spaced set of x values than in the original data)

You could also take a look at the `sjPlot` package, which does a lot of this stuff automatically ...

You need both an unbalanced data set and a non-linear (e.g. polynomial) model for the fixed effects to see this effect.

- if the model is linear, then you don't notice missing values because the linear interpolation done by `geom_line()` works perfectly
- if the data are balanced then there are no gaps to get weirdly filled by linear interpolation

Generate an example with quadratic effects and an unbalanced data set; fit the model

```
library(lme4)
set.seed(101)
dd <- expand.grid(id=factor(1:10),x=1:10)
dd$y <- simulate(~poly(x,2)+(poly(x,2)|id),
                 newdata=dd,
                 family=gaussian,
                 newparams=list(beta=c(0,0,0.1),
                                theta=rep(0.1,6),
                                sigma=1))[[1]]
## subsample randomly (missing values)
dd <- dd[sort(sample(nrow(dd),size=round(0.7*nrow(dd)))),]
m1 <- lmer(y ~ poly(x,2) + (poly(x,2)|id) , data = dd)
```

Naive prediction and plot:

```
dd$pred1 <- predict(m1,re.form=NA)

library(ggplot2)
p11 <- (ggplot(data = dd, aes(x = x, y = y))
    + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm",formula=y~poly(x,2))
)
p11 + geom_line(aes(y=pred1,group = id) ,col="red", lwd = 0.5)
```

Now generate a balanced data set. This version generates 51 evenly spaced points between the min and max - this will be useful if the original data are unevenly spaced.  If you have NA values in your `x` variable, don't forget `na.rm=TRUE` ...

```
pframe <- with(dd,expand.grid(id=levels(id),x=seq(min(x),max(x),length.out=51)
```

Make predictions, and overlay them on the original plot:

```
pframe$pred1 <- predict(m1,newdata=pframe,re.form=NA)    
p11 + geom_line(data=pframe,aes(y=pred1,group = id) ,col="red", lwd = 0.5)
```

Comment: Thank you for your  clarification. As i told you in my previous comment, my X variable is the age at each wave (time step). I used age as the time steps are not equally separated. So that will bring additional unbalance to the data.

Comment: Also the underlying objective of this work is :to determine the overall trend of the data and whether that overall trend has captured by my linear mixed effects models ,by plotting predictions at population level. In that perspective ,is it possible to to tell me whether i am using ggplot package correctly ? Thank you once again

Comment: seems reasonable.